# Where in the OpenGL spec does it say POINT rasterization is clipped to the viewport?

Tags: opengl, specifications

When drawing with `GL_POINTS` if a point is just inside the viewport but the square created by setting `gl_PointSize` makes a square that is outside the viewport, where in the OpenGL Spec does it say that square is or is not  clipped to the viewport?

[image]

In other words in the diagram above, where in the spec does it say if the red part does or does not get rasterized?

Note: I am not interested in the pragmatic, effective answer. I already know that. I'm interested in where in the spec this behavior is defined as having read the spec I can't find it. It might be staring me in the face but AFAICT that red area is supposed to be rasterized unless I've enabled the scissor test but testing across multiple GPUs and OSes it is not rasterized.

As a non-spec reference there's [this](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/features/KilgardTechniques/oglpitfall/) which suggests the red area should be rasterized but testing across 4 OSes and 6 GPUs all of them clip. I'm not seeing where the spec changed.

Comment: The spec does not state that it shouldn't be drawn. If taken literally, even with GL 4.6 it should appear. The clipping is done before the viewport is even considered, and there always were some corner cases were the resulting fragments would lie outside of the viewport, the point size is only one of them (another interesting one is drawing lines at the outer edges of the viewing volume - due to the consisntency requirement of the rounding, on one side, it would have to round to a pixel besides the viewport). However, most modern GL implementations seem to limit drawing to the viewport...

Answer (score 0):

Considering the latest specs at this moment, [glspec46.core.pdf](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf).

We've got on page 468 the main section **14.4 points** and on page 470 there is the subsection **14.4.1 Basic Point Rasterization**. I understand that subsection is what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that section covers POINTS rasterization but it says absolutely nothing about clipping and what happens in the situation shown in the question. In fact it comes after section 13.7, "Primitive Clipping" which makes it pretty clear the only thing "clipped" is the center point itself. What happens to the square put around that point is not covered, at least AFAICT.

Comment: Mmm, I see, so neither `13.7` nor `14.4` solved your question, what about subsection `11.1.3.10` ?

Comment: I give up then :) . Maybe you should ask directly the Khronos guys?